API route raises `fastapi.HTTPException`, test is executed successfully, codecov says "no, it's not covered"
I wrote a couple of tests for my API, for example for this route of /login:
@router.post("/login", response_model=schemas.TokenResponse)
async def login_for_access_token(
        form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(),
        user_interactor: UserInteractor = Depends(get_user_interactor),
        token_interactor: TokenInteractor = Depends(get_token_interactor),
        config: AppConfig = Depends(get_config),
        security_service: SecurityService = Depends(get_security_service)
):
    # If user with given username/pass found - returns user object, 
    # if not found due to any reason - None
    user = await user_interactor.verify_user_password(form_data.username, form_data.password)  
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    # .. some logic .. 
    return schemas.TokenResponse(..)

Following tests were written:
async def test_login_user(client: AsyncClient, test_user):
    response = await client.post(
        "/api/v1/auth/login",
        data={"username": test_user.username, "password": "testpassword"}
    )
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert "access_token" in response.json()
    assert "refresh_token" in response.json()
    assert response.json()["token_type"] == "bearer"


async def test_login_invalid_credentials(client: AsyncClient):
    response = await client.post(
        "/api/v1/auth/login",
        data={"username": "nonexistentuser", "password": "wrongpassword"}
    )
    assert response.status_code == 401
    assert "Incorrect username or password" in response.json()["detail"]
    assert "WWW-Authenticate" in response.headers
    assert response.headers["WWW-Authenticate"] == "Bearer"

It is obvious that both parts for first condition - the one responsible for checking whether such user exists in DB or not - are met in tests, but CodeCov thinks otherwise:

Worth mentioning, both tests pass without any errors thrown and behavior is as expected.
What am I missing in my tests so that code coverage tool will mark if not user: and following line as covered?

Tried to do following, all options failed:

Called pytest from CLI as pytest <path to test folder> -vv -rw --cov=<path to api> --cov-report=term-missing instead checking app.codecov.io - same result, same percentage;
Tried wrapping call of client to:

async def test_login_invalid_credentials(client: AsyncClient):
    with pytest.raises(fastapi.HTTPException) as err:
         response = await client.post(..)

    # asserts here

Test failed cause no fastapi.HTTPException is thrown.

Edit 1, definition of verify_user_password:
    async def verify_user_password(
            self,
            username: str,
            password: str
    ) -> Optional[schemas.User]:
        user: Optional[UoWModel] = await self.user_gateway.get_by_username(username)
        if not user:
            return None
        if await self.user_gateway.verify_password(user, password, self.security_service):
            return schemas.User.model_validate(user._model)
        return None


Did you try running with an alternative coverage library such as Coverage.py? Did you try attaching a debugger and stepping through the code to make sure that this is the actual exception being raised? Are you sure codecov is async compatible in relation to exceptions? (I'm not familiar with codecov, so I couldn't say - but it should be quick to write a test to check) What is the definition of verify_user_password?

@MatsLindh

Did you try running with an alternative coverage library such as Coverage.py?

Not yet, will try if any other fix options gonna fail.
Debugger - yes, and yes, it steps in line with HTTPException.
Yes, checked, codecov is async compatible.
Definition - of verify_.. - added as edit to post.

Are you sure the error are from that exception?
change
detail="Incorrect username or password"

to other message and see if it pass the test. Probablly, one of the dependencies are thorowing the same error.
